# Select Div Title Text and Make Array With Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add the text from all divs Title Attributes to an array but I can't seem to select the right thing.

I need the title because it will contain the string that I need to use.

Here are three divs with different titles

```
<div class = 'test' title='title1'>Hello</div>
<div class = 'test' title='title2'>goodbye</div>
<div class = 'test' title='title2'>goodbye</div>
```

Here is my Jquery so far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$array = $('[title][title!=]').each(function(){
  $(this).attr("title").makeArray;})

 alert($array)

});
```

The alert just says [Object object]

In my example I'm trying to select create an array that contains [Title1, Title2, Title3].

Can anyone help me do this?

**********************************UPDATE**************************************

Thanks the first one worked perfectly. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var array = $.map($('[title][title!=""]'), function(el) { return el.title });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7j8L/1/)

Selects all elements that has a title attribute that is not empty, and maps the titles to an array

Answer (score 2):

```
var theArray = []; // set an empty array to a variable outside of scope

$('.test').each(function() { // loop through all the .test divs
    var theTitle = $(this).attr('title'); // selects the text of the title for the current .test element
    theArray.push(theTitle); // this adds the text of the current title to the array
});

console.log(theArray); // just to test and make sure it worked, remove once verify
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
var titles = $('.test').map(function(){
    return this.title;
}).get();
```

References:

- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).